# Android intent.putExtra() from Service to Activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity

For some time now I'm trying to pass the simple one `String` data from the `Service` to the `Activity` with `Intent.putExtra()` but with no success however. `Intent.getStringExtra()` is always `NULL`

SERVICE CODE:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(Consts.INTERNET_ERROR, "error");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(intent);
```

ACTIVITY CODE:

```
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String test = "temp";
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();
    if (b != null) {
        test = b.getString(Consts.INTERNET_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to implement onNewIntent, the intent in your service is sent to your activity through onNewIntent.

Comment: Just call [getIntent().getStringExtra(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra(java.lang.String)). You didn't put a bundle into the intent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To elaborate my comment above, getIntent returns the original intent as documented  at
[1]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)
[1]:

The intent from the service is passed to your activity through onNewIntent which is called before onResume. Thus if you override onNewIntent you will get the intended string.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    // set the string passed from the service to the original intent
       setIntent(intent);

}
```

Then your code onResume will work.

Comment: Hmm sounds promising.. Will try now

Comment: Works!! Great.. Tnx man.I dont know how I didn't thought on that, as I used onNewIntent few times till now.. Doesn't mater now. Thank you very much.

Comment: this also worked for me when i needed to pass back from current activity to an activity that on pause

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you add the `String` in the service code, however you can run the following code to send the string.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString(Consts.INTERNET_ERROR, "Your String Here");
intent.putExtras(b);
intent.setAction(Consts.INTERNET_ERROR);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: When using your solution in Activity code `Bundle b=i.getExtras();` I got `NULL`. Tested right now...

Answer (score 0):

First: try to move your code from onResume to onStart:

```
public void onStart() {

    super.onStart();

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String test = "temp";
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();
    if (b != null) {
        test = b.getString(Consts.INTERNET_ERROR);
    }
}
```

If it still not working try with this:

First activity:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(firstActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("mystring",strValue)' <=your String
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Second activity:

```
 String str = getIntent.getExtras().getString("mystring");<=get string
```

and check here for some informations:

[How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Comment: When someone downvoting a user should write motivations,thanks!

Comment: It's wasn't me :)  I'm sending the data from Service to Activity, not from Activity to Activity..

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling

```
extras.getString();
```

Try calling:

```
intent.getStringExtra("key");
```

Also, are you starting the activity directly **FROM** the service? Or are you already running on the activity and simply want to receive data from the service?

Comment: I simply want to receive data from the service.. Tnx for your effort